# Swift 3 String has no member components

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm working with Swift 3, and I'm trying to separate user input into 2 different strings. I've looked all over and everywhere I look says that for swift 3, I should use:

```
String.components(separatedBy: " ").
```

However when I use that in my code like so:

```
let userInput = readLine()
let arrayOfInput = userInput!.components(separatedBy: ", ")
```

then on compiling, I'm given an error saying

```
Value of type 'String' has no member 'components'
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`? *hint hint*